# Solve $n < e^{6 \sqrt{n}}$

Tags: inequality

> Find for which values of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $$n < e^{6 \sqrt{n}}.$$

I tried to use the inequality $(1 + x) \leq e^x$, but from this, I can only find that the inequality holds for $n > 36$. **But I need to get $n$ as small as possible.**

I also tried the induction on $n$, but I stucked in the induction step. In particular, in showing that $e^{6\sqrt{n}} + 1 \leq e^{6\sqrt{n+1}}$.

I appreciate any help and suggestions.

Comment: try deriving. You have already $1<e^6$, so I suspect it is true for every $n$

Comment: I will give you a **blind guess**, which may be the **wrong approach**; it is just an idea that may or may not lead anywhere.  I would let $\displaystyle f(x) = e^{(6\sqrt{x})} ~-~ x$, and look at the behavior of $f'(x).$

Comment: Are you allowed to take one more term in the power series, i.e. $e^x \ge 1 + x + \frac{x^2}2$?

Comment: @player3236 I think yes.

Comment: Then it follows that $e^{6\sqrt n} > 18n$.

Comment: Thank you to all of you. I start focus on the hint from @user2661923 and this give me also the solution (so I do not try the other hints).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $e^{3x} > 3x \ge x$ for $x\ge 0$. Apply this to $x = \sqrt{n}$ to get $e^{3\sqrt{n}} > \sqrt{n}$. Square both sides and you have $e^{6\sqrt{n}} > n$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

*(Based on hint from user2661923, see the comments above.)*

I set $f(x) = e^{6\sqrt{x}} - x$. The first derivation of $f(x)$ is $$f'(x) = 3 \frac{e^{6\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}} - 1.$$

We note that $f(1) = e^6 - 1 > 0$. Moreover, it is not hard to check that $f'(x) > 0$ for $x \in [1, +\infty)$. Thus $f$ is increasing on $[1, +\infty)$ and $f(1) > 0$. Therefore $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [1, +\infty)$. It implies that $x < e^{6\sqrt{x}}.$

And my question easily follows.

Comment: For completeness, I suggest that you edit your answer
to demonstrate that $f'(x) > 0$, for all $x > 1.$
One way of doing this is to interpret $f'(x)$ as 
$3 \times e^{[g(x)]} - 1,$ and explicitly examine
the behavior of $g(x) = 6\sqrt{x} - (\log x/2).$
Again, a **blind guess** is to examine $g'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality holds for all positive $x$, so effectively that a proof seems overkill :-)

(Notice that $0<e^{6\sqrt0}$ and $1<\dfrac6{2\sqrt x}e^{6\sqrt x}$.)

---

Or using Taylor,

$$n<1+6\sqrt n+18n+\cdots$$